# Default text encoding on iOS

Tags: objective-c

I'm creating an app based on a API server. The server is currently in UTF-8 encoding.

Rather than write a line of code every time the API is accessed to re-encode text, I thought I may as well just set the server API to have the same text encoding as the app.

Only problem is I can't find out the default encoding!

Where would I find this information, and can I change the default encoding on the app?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default encoding. `NSString` can have various encodings internally.

I know that on Mac OS X, ASCII, UTF-8 and UTF-16 w/ host byte order are always among possible internal representations, iOS shouldn't be different, though I'm not totally sure. I think it's safe to assume that `stringWithUTF8String:` will not cause any extra re-encoding.

Comment: Thanks Hamster. Perhaps I misunderstand the basis of encoding, but if I take text from a server, and then read it (say NSLog, or show it in a UILabel), it must be reading/storing it using some kind of encoding? I am having encoding issues, in that certain letters/symbols are appearing incorrectly, so I assume that the export of UTF-8 from the SQL API is being encoded/read differently in the app. Can I set NSString to always use UTF-8 encoding somewhere?

Comment: @Tim There is only one way to do UTF-8, it can't be done differently. Either you have bug when making `NSString` out of utf-8 bytes, or your UTF-8 is not really UTF-8, or there is no bug but the display font doesn't have glyphs for some symbols.

Comment: alright hamster, there must be something in a plugin that's converting it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

NSString's static method  will do the job

```
+ (NSStringEncoding)defaultCStringEncoding;
```